# Supersaturation of $K_{s,t}$ in graphs with many edges

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I was trying to solve the following problem from Yufei Zhao's book "Graph Theory and Additive Combinatorics":

> **Exercise 1.4.12 (Density KST).** Prove that for every pair of positive integers $s\leq t$, there are constants $C,c>0$ such that
> every $n$-vertex graph with $p\binom{n}{2}$ edges contains at least
> $cp^{st}n^{s+t}$ copies of $K_{s,t}$, provided that $p\geq Cn^{-1/s}$.

Before this problem he discusses Kovari-Sos-Turan theorem which says that

> For any positive integers $s\leq t$ and for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we
> have $$ex(n,K_{s,t})\leq
>  \frac{(t-1)^{1/s}}{2}n^{2-1/s}+\frac{s-1}{2}n.$$

Also he discusses the Supersaturation Theorem

> For every $\varepsilon>0$ and graph $H$ there exist some $\delta>0$
> and $n_0$ such that every graph on $n\geq n_0$ vertices with at least
> $(\pi(H)+\varepsilon)\binom{n}{2}$ edges contains at least $\delta
>  n^{\nu(H)}$ copies of $H$ as a subgraph.

I am trying to combine the last two result to obtain the first one but do not know how to do it.

I'd be very grateful if someone can show the proof! Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297118/kovari-sos-turan-theorem This is seemingly related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think double-counting reasoning should work.

---

If suffices to show that it holds when $n$ is sufficiently large.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with $|V| = n$ and $|E| = p\binom{n}{2}$.
Define $M = |\{(S \in \binom{V}{s}, v \in V): S \subseteq N(v)\}|$, where $N(v)$ is the set of neighbors of $v$ in $G$.
We define $f(S) = |\{v \in V: S \subseteq N(v)\}|, \forall S \in \binom{V}{s}$.
Then we have
$$M = \sum_{v \in V} \binom{|N(v)|}{s} = \sum_{S \in \binom{V}{s}} f(S).$$
We use Jensen's to obtain
$$\sum_{S \in \binom{V}{s}} f(S) = M = n * \frac{M}{n} = n * {\sum_{v \in V} \binom{|N(v)|}{s}} \geq n \binom{\sum_{v \in V}|N(v)| /n}{s} 
= n \binom{2p\binom{n}{2} /n}{s}
= n \binom{p(n-1)}{s}.$$

We use Jensen's again to the number of copies of $K_{s,t}$:
$$\sum_{S \in \binom{V}{s}} \binom{f(s)}{t} 
\geq \binom{n}{s} \binom{\sum_{S} f(S)/\binom{n}{s}}{t} 
\geq \binom{n}{s} \binom{n \binom{p(n-1)}{s}/\binom{n}{s}}{t}
= \Omega(n^s) * \binom{n \frac{(pn-p)(pn-p-1)\ldots(pn-p-s+1)}{n(n-1)\ldots(n-s+1)}}{t}
\geq \Omega(n^s) * \binom{((pn-p)n^{1/s}/n)^s}{t}
= \Omega(n^s) * \binom{\Omega(p^s n)}{t} 
= \Omega(n^s) * \Omega(p^{st}n^t) = \Omega(p^{st} n^{s+t}).$$

More specifically, when $n \geq 100s$ and $p^s n \geq C^s \geq 100t / 0.99^s$,
$$
\sum_{S \in \binom{V}{s}} \binom{f(s)}{t}
\geq \frac{0.99^s}{s!} n^s \times \binom{(0.99p n^{1/s})^s}{t}
\geq \frac{0.99^s}{s!} n^s \times \binom{0.99^s p^s n}{t}
\geq \frac{0.99^s}{s!} n^s \times \frac{0.99^{s+t}}{t!} (0.99^s p^s n)^t
\geq \frac{0.99^s}{s!} * \frac{0.99^{s+t}}{t!} * 0.99^{st} * p^{st}n^{s+t}.$$

---

The condition on $p$ ($p = \Omega(n^{-1/s})$) is used to guarantee that $\Omega(p^s n)$ is not $o(1)$ (when $n \rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! But some moments are not so clear: Using Jensen's inequality you show that it is $\geq n \binom{\sum_{v\in V} |N(v)|/n}{s}$ which is equal to $n\binom{2|E|/n}{s}=\frac{n}{s!} \left(\frac{2|E|}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2|E|}{n}-1\right)\dots \left(\frac{2|E|}{n}-(s-1)\right)$. Can you give more details why it is $\Omega(p^sn^{s+1})$? I really want to see how did you get it and what is the constant there.

Comment: I tried to obtain this lower bound but it did not work out. So I would be very grateful if you can show all the details. The original problem is nontrivial and it would be good to see all the details. Thank you!

Comment: P.S. the bounty expires in one day and I'd like to give you the bounty but it would be great if you can go over these unclear questions.

Comment: I awarded you bounty since it would expired in 1 hours. I am wondering can you explain my question which I asked above?

Comment: Thank you! I updated my answer!

Comment: @ZFR I updated my answer, adding more details!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also posted an answer where I wrote all the details. Please take a look and let me know what do you think about it. I'd be grateful to hear your opinion about that!

Comment: Sorry but you did not reply to my comment

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:** The proof was already given by @VezenBU. So in this answer I am just filling out some details.

Assume that $G=(V,E)$ is a graph such that $\nu(G)=n\geq s+t$ and $e(G)=p\binom{n}{2}$.

Let's consider the set of $s$-stars in graph $G$:
\begin{equation*}
    M:=\left\{(A,v)\in \binom{V}{s}\times V: v\sim A\right\}.    
\end{equation*}

Easy to see that
\begin{align*}
    |M|&=\sum \limits_{v\in V}\sum_{\substack{A\in \binom{V}{s} \\A\sim v}} 1=\sum_{v\in V}\left|\left\{A\in \binom{V}{S}:v\sim A\right\} \right|=\\
    &=\sum \limits_{v\in V}\left|\left\{A:A\in \binom{N(v)}{s}\right\} \right|=\sum_{v\in V}\binom{\deg(v)}{s}.
\end{align*}
The function $f_s:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
f_s(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x(x-1)\dots(x-(s-1))}{s!}, & \text{if } x\geq s-1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise } 
\end{cases}    
\end{equation*}
is convex and for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ we have $f_s(n)=\binom{n}{s}$ (also $f_s$ is nondecreasing). Therefore by Jensen's inequality,
\begin{align*}
    |M|&=\sum \limits_{v\in V}f_s(\deg(v))=n\sum \limits_{v\in V}\frac{1}{n}f_s(\deg(v))\\
    &\geq nf_s\left( \sum \limits_{v\in V}\frac{\deg(v)}{n}\right)=nf_s\left(\frac{2e(G)}{n}\right)\\
    &=nf_s\left(p(n-1)\right).
\end{align*}

For each $A\in \binom{V}{s}$, consider $f(A):=\left|\left\{ v\in V: v\sim A\right\} \right|$. The definition of $M$ implies that $|M|=\sum \limits_{A\in \binom{V}{s}}f(A)$. The number of copies of $K_{s,t}$ in graph $G$ is
\begin{align*}
    \sum \limits_{A\in \binom{V}{s}}\binom{f(A)}{t}&=\sum \limits_{A\in \binom{V}{s}}f_t(f(A))=\binom{n}{s}\sum \limits_{A\in \binom{V}{s}}\binom{n}{s}^{-1}f_t(f(A))\\
    &\geq\binom{n}{s}f_t \left(\sum_{A\in \binom{V}{s}}\binom{n}{s}^{-1}f(A)\right)=\binom{n}{s}f_t\left(\frac{|M|}{\binom{n}{s}}\right).
\end{align*}

If one takes $C=2s t^{1/s}$, i.e. $p\geq 2s t^{1/s} n^{-1/s}$, then $p\geq \dfrac{2s}{n^{1/s}}\geq \dfrac{2s}{n}>\dfrac{2s-2}{n}\geq \dfrac{s-1}{n-1}$, i.e. $p(n-1)> s-1$.

The following inequality holds:
\begin{equation}
\label{size of M}
        |M|\geq \frac{1}{(2s)^s s!}p^sn^{s+1}.
\end{equation}

Since $p\geq 2s t^{1/s} n^{-1/s}$ which implies that $p(n-1)>s-1$ and hence
\begin{align*}
    |M|&\geq nf_s(p(n-1))=n\cdot \dfrac{(pn-p)(pn-p-1)\cdot (pn-p-(s-1))}{s!}=\\
    &=p^sn^{s+1}(s!)^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{pn}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{1}{n} -\frac{s-1}{pn}\right). 
\end{align*}
Each of these brackets is positive since $p(n-1)>s-1$ because we assumed that $p\geq 2s t^{1/s} n^{-1/s}$.
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
    |M|\geq p^sn^{s+1}(s!)^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n} -\frac{s-1}{pn}\right)^s.
\end{equation*}
Since $n\geq 2$, then $1-\frac{1}{n}\geq \frac{1}{2}$. Also since $p\geq 2s t^{1/s} n^{-1/s}$, then $pn\geq 2s$ and hence $$1-\frac{1}{n} -\frac{s-1}{pn}\geq \frac{1}{2}-\frac{s-1}{2s}=\frac{1}{2s}.$$
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
    |M|\geq \frac{1}{(2s)^s s!}p^sn^{s+1}.
\end{equation*}

So we know that the number of copies of $K_{s,t}$ in graph $G$ is at least $\binom{n}{s}f_t\left(|M|\binom{n}{s}^{-1}\right)$ and since $f_t$ is nondecreasing it follows that
\begin{equation*}
    \#\ \text{of copies of} \ K_{s,t} \ \text{in graph} \ G\geq \binom{n}{s}f_t\left(\frac{p^sn^{s+1}}{(2s)^s s!}\binom{n}{s}^{-1}\right).
\end{equation*}
One can show that $\beta:=\dfrac{p^sn^{s+1}}{(2s)^s s!}\dbinom{n}{s}^{-1}\geq t$ since $p\geq \dfrac{2s t^{1/s}}{n^{1/s}}$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    f_t(\beta)=\frac{\beta\cdot (\beta-1)\cdot\dots \cdot(\beta-(t-1))}{t!} \geq \frac{\beta\cdot (\beta-1)\cdot\dots \cdot(\beta-(t-1))}{\beta!}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    \#\ &\text{of copies of} \ K_{s,t} \ \text{in graph} \ G\geq \binom{n}{s}\frac{\beta\cdot (\beta-1)\cdot\dots \cdot(\beta-(t-1))}{t!}\geq \\
    &\geq \frac{n(n-1)\cdot (n-(s-1))}{s!}\times \frac{\beta\cdot (\beta-1)\cdot\dots \cdot(\beta-(t-1))}{t!}\geq \\
    & \geq \frac{n^s\beta^t}{s!t!}  \left(1-\frac{s-1}{n}\right)^s\left(1-\frac{t-1}{\beta}\right)^t.
\end{align*}
Since $n\geq s+1$ and $\beta\geq t$ it follows that
\begin{align*}
    \#\ &\text{of copies of} \ K_{s,t} \ \text{in graph} \ G\geq \frac{n^s\beta^t}{s!t!t^t}\left(\frac{2}{s+1}\right)^s.
\end{align*}
Notice that
\begin{align*}
    \beta^t&=\frac{p^{st}n^{st+t}}{(2s)^{st}(s!)^t}\times \frac{(s!)^t}{\left[n(n-1)\dots (n-(s-1)) \right]^t}\geq \\
    &\geq \frac{p^{st}n^{st+t}}{(2s)^{st}n^{st}}=\frac{p^{st}n^t}{(2s)^{st}}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we obtain that
\begin{equation*}
    \#\ \text{of copies of} \ K_{s,t} \ \text{in graph} \ G\geq\left( \frac{2^s}{s!t!t^t (2s)^{st}(s+1)^s}\right)p^{st}n^{s+t}.
\end{equation*}

> In summary, we were able to show that for every pair of positive
> integers $s\leq t$, there are constants $C:=2st^{1/s},\ 
>  c:=\dfrac{2^s}{s!t!t^t(2s)^{st}(s+1)^s}$ such that every $n$-vertex
> graph $(n\geq s+t)$ with $p\binom{n}{2}$ edges, where $p\geq
>  Cn^{-1/s}$ contains at least $cp^{st}n^{s+t}$ copies of $K_{s,t}$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Your proof looks complete and good! I just edited some typos.